# Crear varios graficos a la vez con R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy creando graficos con R, uso ggplot, a continuación os pongo el código que uso. Con el obtengo un gráfico donde se ve una linea por cada tipo de color que tengo en los datos. Es decir, 1 gráfico y tres lineas distintas.

Me gustaria sacar un gráfico por cada linea, es decir, tres gráficos y una sola linea.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

A continuacion los datos:

```
library(ggplot2)

library(data.table)
periodo <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3")
talla <- c("180","180","200","180","200","185","183","201","182","205","202","207")
colores <- c("amarillo", "rojo","azul","amarillo", "rojo","azul","amarillo", "rojo","azul","amarillo", "rojo","azul")

datos <- data.table(cbind(periodo,colores,talla)) 

ggplot(datos, aes(x=periodo, y=talla, group=colores)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = colores, color = colores))+
  geom_point(aes(color=colores))+
  theme(legend.position="top")
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te sirve un gráfico con tres paneles podrías hacerlo así:

```
ggplot(datos, aes(x=periodo, y=talla, group=colores)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = colores, color = colores))+
  geom_point(aes(color=colores))+
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  facet_wrap(~colores, ncol = 2)
```

Agregando la última línea `ggplot()` crea un panel para cada categoría de la variable colores. **Con el argumento `ncol=` podrías ajustar cuantos paneles salen por columna.**

Otra aproximación es cortar a tus datos en una lista de data.frame (o data.table, en este caso es lo mismo) por cada categoría de color y aplicar una funcional que genere una lista de gráficos, uno para cada elemento de la lista de datos. Después usar `purrr::walk()` para imprimirlos dentro de un documento de `rmarkdown` con salida a .pdf.

```
#Creo una lista de gráficos con una función anónima dentro de un lapply

graficos <- lapply(split(datos, datos$colores), function(x) {
  ggplot(x, aes(x=periodo, y=talla, group=colores)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype = colores, color = colores))+
    geom_point(aes(color=colores))+
    theme(legend.position="top") })

#Uso un funcional que produce solo side efect para imprimirlos después

purrr::walk(graficos, print)
```

Creo que en R se podría manipular el dispositivo de gráficos para que cree múltiples gráficos en un mismo .pdf. En mi experiencia es bastante complicado ajustarlo para que salga exactamente como uno quiere y es más simple la aproximación con `rmarkdown`, porque los parámetros (márgenes, tamaños de gráficos, proporciones de ancho-altura) se manipula en un entorno LaTeX que está definido por el tamaño del "papel" donde se va a imprimir. El paquete `tinytex` facilita mucho hacer una instalación mínima de LaTeX en tu computadora, si es que no lo has instalado aún.

Comment: Me parece una buena solucion. 
El problema que tengo es que no son 3 graficos como en el ejemplo que puse. Son más y al meter esta opcion los graficos salen muy mal.
Quizas seria mejor generarlos y ser capaz de exportarlos a un PDF, para poder apreciar bien los graficos.

Comment: Edité la respuesta con dos alternativas: ajustar `ncol` trabajando con paneles o crear una lista de gráficos y usar rmarkdown para producir el pdf

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentar la opcion de sacarlo en lista ya que son muchos.

Comment: También está la posibilidad de trabajar con la lista de gráficos, pero usar `rmarkdown` con salida html en lugar de pdf. De ese modo te ahorras la dependencia de LaTeX y los problemas de paginado intrínsecos a trabajar con un formato pensado para impresión. Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que entiendo tu problema, lo que te pasa es que al poner la opción de múltiples gráficos se ven super mal, esto es porque no están en una escala adecuada , con esto se podría ver bien:

```
 ggplot(datos, aes(x=periodo, y=talla, group=colores)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = colores, color = colores))+
  geom_point(aes(color=colores))+
  theme(legend.position="top") + 
  facet_wrap(~colores, ncol = 2 ,scales = "free")
```

Comment: También es una buena opción. El problema es que tengo muchos graficos para la pantalla de graficos. Creo que la mejor manera es sacarlos en un PDF, ir sacando de 6 en 6 en varias hojas o algo así.
Muchas gracias, porque esta opcion la voy a usar cuando sean menos graficos.